# CSV download is splitting into CSV and CSV.part

Tags: macos, csv, download, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'd like to download a CSV file from JupyterLab.

It's 66MB and it shows the file is downloading, but it's split into CSV and CSV.part.

According to JupyterLab, the download has finished but they haven't combined into a single CSV.

When I open the csv.part, it says there are no applications to open it.

When I open the csv, it's empty.

I've tried re-downloading and it's always the same.

What do I do here?

[image: RT]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever application you used to download the file - a web browser? Safari? Chrome? - downloads the data into a temporary file (with `.part` on the end) and it is supposed to rename it to `myfile.csv` after the download has completed.

For whatever reason, it has not done this last step.

Simply delete the empty file `myfile.csv` and rename `myfile.csv.part` to `myfile.csv`. You will see a warning ("Are you sure you want to rename this?") - yes. You are sure.

There is nothing magical about file name extensions, except of course that they tell MacOS which application to open the file with. They should also give you a clear indication of what sort of data is in the file, but this is not actually enforced by anything. If you rename a file to something inappropriate for the content (e.g. if you name your file "myfile.mp3"), it simply won't load into the application as the data isn't valid. But, there is nothing special about the .part file - the name is just supposed to indicate that the download (probably) hasn't finished yet. Except in this case, I assume you know that it has.

(This seems like a bug to me, perhaps with JupyterLab - but that's beside the point).